# Collapsing database fields to rows using field names as values

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So microsoft access sql is a bit limited but I am curious if its possible to use some field names to generate values for rows. It is a bit hard to explain but here is an example:

```
IDNum   010101   010102   010103
  1     5/20/19  5/21/19  5/22/19
  2     5/28/19  5/28/19  5/30/19
```

Each field name has 3 2 digit values in it which represent version, process, step. So the first field is version 1, process 1, step 1 . These can go up to 10 so I included 2 digit values as shown. I am trying to collapse the table to as follows:

```
IDNum   Date    Version   Process   Step
  1     5/20/19    1         1       1
  1     5/21/19    1         1       2
  1     5/22/19    1         1       3
  2     5/28/19    1         1       1
  2     5/28/19    1         1       2
  2     5/30/19    1         1       3
```

Is collapsing the data like this even possible in a single access query? I have been struggling to find a clean all in one solution. We technically have over 60 of these columns so to do individual queries for each seems a bit much.

Any solutions on methodologies explained would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Your "collapse" seems to be making the table bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all`:

```
select idnum, [010101] as date, 1 as version, 1 as process, 1 as step
from t
union all
select idnum, [010102] as date, 1 as version, 1 as process, 2 as step
from t
union all
select idnum, [010103] as date, 1 as version, 1 as process, 3 as step
from t;
```